# Open iframe based on cookie value

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set up a piece of code so that an iframe only loads if the content of the cookie `'cookie_consent_user_accepted' = true`.

I have managed to do this with other scripts but not iframe and am somewhat lost on where to start with an iframe.

Comment: What about something like this? https://borlabs.io/borlabs-cookie/iframe-demo/#

Answer (score 1):

#### Procedure:

1. Check if the cookie exists or not. Since the name and value of the cookie is constant, simply hardcode it to eliminate few of lines of code.
2. a) If yes, hide the *Accept Cookie* button, create an `iframe` and append it to the container.
   b) If not, add an `eventListener` to the button and wait for user acceptance. Once user accept it, go to *2a*.

#### Code:

<sup>*Note*: Stacksnippet won't support cookie because of security concerns so I'm not using the snippet here</sup>

```
// A function to check whether the cookie exists or not
function checkCookie(){

    // Checking if hardcoded cookie value exists in document.cookie
    if(document.cookie.indexOf('cookie_consent_user_accepted=true')!=-1){

        // If yes, remove message (along with the button and related stuff)
        document.querySelector('.message').remove();

        // Create iframe and append it to the container
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); 
        iframe.src = "https://example.com";
        document.querySelector('.container').append(iframe);
    }
}
```

Sample HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="message">
    Ok with cookies?
    <button class="btn">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Create an `EventListener` for `button#click`

```
function acceptCookie(){
  document.cookie="cookie_consent_user_accepted = true";
  checkCookie();
}
```

Attaching `eventListener` to the `button`

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click',acceptCookie);
```

And check if the cookie exists on window load

```
checkCookie();
```

JSFiddle support cookies so I created a fiddle there. [Here's the link](https://jsfiddle.net/sagarvd01/hxtLjyv2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it with `style="display:none"` and show it with javascript when the cookie is `true`

```html
<body>
    <iframe id="customIframe" style="display:none" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</body>
<script>
    const getCookie = (name) => {
        return document.cookie.split('; ').reduce((r, v) => {
            const parts = v.split('=')
            return parts[0] === name ? decodeURIComponent(parts[1]) : r
        }, '')
    }

    function showIframe() {
        document.getElementById('customIframe').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function tryToShowIframe(){
        if(getCookie('cookie_consent_user_accepted') === 'true'){
            showIframe();
        }
    }

</script>
```

If you are using chrome or firefox, you can also check [how to set a cookies listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/onChanged) so you can try to know when `cookie_consent_user_accepted` was set and show the iframe when that cookie is `true`. This solution is based on Chromium's [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged) API so it does not work on Internet Explorer.

Comment: This looks like the sort of solution I am looking for, however, I have tried using this code and it results in any content below this code being hidden on the website.

Comment: @NathanShoesmith it might be because I wasn't closing the `<iframe>` correctly. Try again, I edited the answer